# Type-safe states with exhaustive pattern matching in Akka Typed

Tags: scala, akka, partialfunction, akka-typed

I started working with Akka Typed to get exhaustive pattern matching on my behaviors, which has been great for the external facing contract of each actor. However, if the actor is a state machine, chances are the different states have state specific commands.

I can hide state-specific commands as private members of the overall command like this:

```
sealed trait Command
final case class Add(id: Int) extends Command
private final case object AccumulationTimeout extends Command
private final case object Ack extends Command
```

However, my two states `accumulating` and `emitting` have to handle each other's commands. I could use `.receivePartial` or include a catch all

```
case _ => Behaviors.unhandled
```

In both cases, I've lost exhaustive pattern matching to make sure I handle my state properly.

I can further refine the commands as such:

```
sealed trait Command

sealed trait Accumulating extends Command
private final case object AccumulationTimeout extends Accumulating

sealed trait Emitting extends Command
private final case object Ack extends Emitting

final case class Add(id: Int) extends Accumulating with Emitting
```

With this I can define `Behavior[Accumulating]` and `Behavior[Emitting]` which both are `Behavior[Command]`, but the catch is that there is no way for either of the behaviors to transition to the other, since both have to return their own type.

I've tried various permutations of `.widen` and `.narrow` to no avail and realize that what I truly need is a way to define a `Behavior` as

```
def receiveMessage[T, V <: T](handler: V => Behavior[T]): Behavior[T] = ???
```

where `handler` would give me exhaustive checking on the narrow type `V` and for any message `T` outside of `V` would return `Behaviors.unhandled`. I just can't seem to make the types work to implement such a function.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to do an initial matching on the state-specific subset of commands. Something like:

```scala
def accumulating: Behavior[Command] = 
  Behaviors.receive { 
    case acc: Accumulating => 
      acc match {
        //... complete for the message subtype or compiler fails...
      }
    case _ => 
      // other state subtypes are 
      Behaviors.unhandled
```

Comment: Which is remarkably close to what my un-typed actors used to look like. I was hoping for a syntactic sugar that made it more explicit than a coding pattern.

Comment: I imagine you could achieve something like your suggested ` V <: T` signature by using a classtag, but there's nothing out of the box that does it.